# Using react-slick and swiper in same project

Tags: swiper.js, slick.js, react-slick, react-swiper

I am one of the developers working on Ecommerce platform build with React. I recently developed a carousel component using Slider from 'react-slick'. Carousel was working fine in test environment until another developer used Swiper, SwiperSlide from 'swiper/react' to build some more complex, dynamic carousel component in the same project. Ever since all my styling went through the roof. Is it possible that his Swiper affected my Slider? Every component has its own scss file with unique class names (except from out of the box slider classes).

In scss file I even tried to encapsulated all my css inside the id of the component, but problem is still there